# Double arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops

Im in the process of learning C and the basis of the class is C primer plus(6th edition). We use Eclipse as an IDE.

For an project we have to create to arrays. One array that takes numbers in a loop and another array that display the cumulative value. So if array 1 has values 1, 5 and 3(out of 10 inputs total) then the resulting input in array 2 should be 9(on the 3th input because of the 3 inputs in array 1).

Im having trouble getting started the right way - anyone here has ideas how I could proceed?
So far I have this for starters but forgive me for it it very weak:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10
void doublearrays (double usernumber);

int main(void)
{
    double usernumbers = 0.0;
    int loop1 = 1;
    while(loop1)
    {
        printf("Type numbers as doubles. \n");
        fflush(stdout);
        loop1 = scanf("%lf", &usernumber);
        if(loop1)
        {
            doublearrays(usernumber);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but `if(loop1)` should be `if(loop1==1)`. Same with the loop condition: `while(loop1)` should be `while(loop1==1)`.

Comment: Start with: creating a statically allocated array, reading fixed number of user's numbers (how can this be done in a loop?), passing array and it's size to a function. Next steps would be asking yourself: do I know how many numbers the user would love to enter? Should I allocate memory dynamically? How do I know that user finished entering numbers?

Comment: User input can have vary length.   Looks like you want to create create dynamic data structure. plain C unfortunately don't have any dynamic containers like vector in C++

Comment: @Vlad 10 inputs in total. No need for dynamic allocation

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude your suggestions that `if(loop)` 'should be' `if(loop==1)` does not make a semantic difference. I assume you know this and that your preference for one over the other, is for readability purposes?

Comment: @MortenJensen It does make a lot of sense considering that `scanf` can return `EOF` which is a non-zero value (must be negative, usually `-1`) and therefore considered "true". If that happens a loop like `while(loop1)` will never stop iterating.

Answer (score 2):

All the text in a homework assignment shall be read:

> For a project we have to create **two arrays**... 10 inputs total...

Why on earth do not you declare them?... You already have defined `SIZE` so

```
double usernumbers[SIZE];
double cumulnumbers[SIZE];
```

Next do yourself a favour and handle one problem at a time:

> One array that takes numbers in a loop...

Ok, so write a loop up to 10 reading floats directly into the array and note how many numbers were received

```
int n;
for(n=0; n<SIZE; n++) {
    if (scanf("%lf", &usernumbers[n]) != 1) break;
}
// ok we now have n number in the first array
```

Let us go on

> and another array that display the cumulative value.

Ok cumul is initially 0. and is incremented on each value from the first array:

```
double cumul = 0.;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    cumul += usernumbers[i];
    cumulnumbers[i] = cumul;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort in helping me. When I write up your code it gives me: "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector" on the scanf line and the culmul and cumulnumbers line(the last and second-to-last).

If I want to print the list with the culmul numbers should I use

printf("The list is &numbers\n");  or?

Answer (score 1):

*(your current code isn't what you need... delete it and then...)*

> anyone here has ideas how I could proceed?

Well the first step would be to actually define some arrays.

```
double input[SIZE];
double cum[SIZE];
```

The next step would be a loop to read input.

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    if (scanf("%lf", &input[i]) != 1)
    {
        // Input error - add error handling - or just exit
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The next step is to add code for calculating the the cumulative value.

I'll leave that for you as an exercise.

The last step is to print the array which I also will leave to you as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward way of doing this, which would also use two arrays and a loop construct would be to create something like this.. I've changed the doubles to integers. (and i am also ignoring any errors from scanf()).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

static void
print_array(int *arr, const char *arr_name)
{
   int i;
   printf("%s  = [");
   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      printf("%d%s", arr[i], i < SIZE -1 ? ",":"");
   printf("]\n");
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int i;
   int input[SIZE];
   int cumsum[SIZE];

   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      int _input;

      printf("Give me numbers!\n");
      fflush(stdout);
      scanf("%d", &_input); /* assuming integer */
      input[i] = _input;
      cumsum[i] = i > 0 ? cumsum[i-1] + _input : _input;
   }

   print_array(input, "input");
   print_array(cumsum, "cumulative");

   return 0;
}
```

or If you'd like to play around with pointers and have a bit more compact version.. perhaps this could be something to study to help you understand pointers, it does the same thing as my code above

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10
static int data[SIZE*2];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int *input_p = &data[0];
   int *cumsum_p = &data[0] + SIZE;

   for (; input_p != &data[0] + SIZE; input_p++, cumsum_p++)
   {
      printf("Give me numbers!\n");
      scanf("%d", input_p);
      *cumsum_p = input_p == &data[0] ? *input_p : *(cumsum_p-1) + *input_p;
   }
}
```